# Отправить в параметра AJAX запроса несколько значений

Tags: javascript, ajax

Для реализации добавления комментариев, в "params" AJAX запроса необходимо отправить несколько значений. Как это реализовать на чистом javascript.
В ниже приведённом участке кода, отправляется только одно значение, текст комментария.

```js
      var comment = document.getElementById("textCommentID").value;  
      params = "comment=" + comment;      
      request = new ajaxRequest()
```

Comment: Создайте объект и отправьте его

Comment: а что вам мешает добавить новые параметры:   params = "comment=" + comment+'&fild='+data+'&fild2='+data2;